# Vertical Punchcard with chartjs

Tags: chart.js

Is it possible to create a chart like this?
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Thanks in advance

Comment: I guess it should be possible with Bubble Chart: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bubble.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is possible by adding the property `pointRadius` in your dataset object and give it an array for the radius of each point

Working example (with text on the Y axes as seems you want, to get the desired result each line will need to be a different dataset): https://jsfiddle.net/Leelenaleee/2gtndc3h/1/

dataset example:

```
{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: ['', 'Request Added', 'Request Added', 'Request Added', 'Request Viewed', 'Request Viewed', 'Request Viewed'],
      borderWidth: 1,
      lineTension: 0,
      pointRadius: [2, 4, 6, 18, 0, 12, 20],
    }
```